40's or 50's comedy movie about Hollywood film production
This film had increasingly "chaotic" scenes at the end, two of them I remember:

a person hanging from a window high above the street, suddenly Roman soldiers march over the building's wall so it becomes clear that this is only a camera trick
people running away from an wild-west train, they climb over a black wall, the camera zooms out and they are now in the movie theater, the black wall is just the dark area around the screen, people continue to run away, climbing over the movie theater chairs and climb through another screen

IIRC the different story lines (there was also an "Samson fights lion" part) were caused by different directors / production teams sharing the same studio areas.

Color or black & white?

These sound like Mel Brooks gags.

could it be Hellzapoppin'?

@mjn Thought about it, but I don't remember those scenes. Then again, it's crammed with so many meta gags that I could be wrong.

@Walt you are right - I found Hellzapoppin' on the Internet and could not find any of these scenes

Sorry. Do you remember anything else? The rest of the plot, the actors, any dialogue, where\when you watched it?

The chaos in the finale part seemed to be caused by competing production teams sharing one studio areal.

It's not silent movie, is it? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075222/?ref_=nv_sr_1

Is this a question or an answer? In the latter case you might want to add some elaboration why you think it's an answer. How does it match to the details given in the question?
